# Gluon Connect returns NPE when POSTing using Charm dependencies > 4.3.3

Tags: java, gluon-mobile

When trying to send a POST request I use the following code:

```
RestClient post = RestClient.create()
        .method("POST")
        .host(host)
        .path(path)
        .contentType("application/json");
Chicken chicken = new Chicken(name, age);
GluonObservableObject<Chicken> o = DataProvider.storeObject(chicken,
        post.createObjectDataWriter(Chicken.class));
o.exceptionProperty().addListener((obs, ol, nw) -> System.err.println("post: " + nw));
o.initializedProperty().addListener((obs, ol, nw) -> {
    if (nw)
        retrieveList.add(o.get());
});
```

where `Chicken` is a POJO:

```
public class Chicken {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int id = 12;

    public Chicken() {}

    public Chicken(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // getters and setter for all fields, equals and hashcode and toString
}
```

The server endpoint with JAX-RS is

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; " + CHARSET)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; " + CHARSET)
public Response save(JsonObject chicken) {
    // do stuff
    return Response.ok(response).build();
}
```

In the gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:glisten-afterburner:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.3'
}
```

if I specify versions 4.3.2 or 4.3.3 (as above) it works correctly. But if I specify 4.3.4 or 4.3.5 is stops working. On the client the error stream prints

```
post: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and on the server (Wildfly 10.1)

```
11:17:20,839 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-35) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:387)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:121)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:264)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know why is "Cannot consume content type" for 4.3.4 but can for 4.3.3. Couldn't find differences in the javadocs.

I can update the projects on github for a full server-client kind-of-MCVE.

Comment: You have found a bug in Connect 1.4.3. I've just filed an issue to solve it. In the meantime you have to use as dependencies `com.gluonhq:glisten-afterburner:1.2.0` and `com.gluonhq:connect:1.4.2`.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks. Can we have the link to the issue please?

Comment: I've filed it internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug that was introduced recently. As a workaround, you should be able to set the header manually:

```
RestClient post = RestClient.create()
    .method("POST")
    .host(host)
    .path(path)
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
//    .contentType("application/json");
```

The bug itself will be fixed in the next version.